# Get point coordinates on a path between 2 points by distance

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a path tracking map built with Mapbox, where I have different points and a straight line between them.

I would like to place a marker between two points based on a distance from Point A to Point B on the defined straight line.

Is there a method in Mapbox that returns the coordinates of a point at a specified distance along a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. However, there is in Turf: http://turfjs.org/docs/#along